# how to send 2d barcode sms

Tags: asp.net

any one know how to send 2d barcode on sms or which type of sms format require to send barcode image on sms?

Comment: Sounds like proprietary technology: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sms_barcode

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to send the barcode as a picture in an MMS.